# Mi max not able to boot up after flashing

Tags: boot-loop, xiaomi

I successfully flashed my Mi Max prime 3/64GB to helium_global_images_V9.1.2.0.NBDMIEI_20171109.0000.00_7 ROM using mi flash in edl mode. Now the problem is the phone doesn't start up. It shows mi logo and android logo down the screen, its loading dots go for a few seconds, it vibrates and button lights gets on, and then it switches off completely.

I also tried going to recovery mode and wiped all data after flash. but it seems nothing works.

my device is not unlocked that's why I flashed it in EDL, and I prefer it to stay this way if possible.

any suggestions?

Comment: Probably you flashed the wrong ROM file, try reverting back to the stock firmware

Comment: @esQmo_ where can I get the right rom? how to know it's stock rom?

Comment: Usually stock firmwares are downloaded from official website. But I' d suggest you take a tour on needrom.com

Comment: @esQmo_ I downloaded and installed the stock rom from official miui site. still no luck. the same happens

Comment: Did you wipe data and cache from the recovery this time?

Comment: @esQmo_ this time I couldn't go to recovery mode because of low battery. looks like it is charging so slowly, like 2%, 3% in whole day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is with the battery. the connector that connects the battery to the main board was damaged. so I guess it didn't provide enough output for the main board to boot the operatinng system up.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the one who gave you a wrong answer previously 
About battery connector seems he have no idea that problem it's happening because you phone bootloader locked if you can unlock it you will just need to wipe data then start it up normal.. i experienced this problem in mi max 1 the 32gb version ... try to search for unlocking your device by ADB method it will work with you

Comment: OP *himself* was the one who wrote the previous answer - he knows best what solved his problem.